# Is there a Facebook post character limit difference between group and individual pages?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I am a member of several open groups on Facebook, and I notice that in the group people are posting quite large posts.  The suggestion from the group owner was that maybe the limit is different for groups.

Anyone know if you can alter the personal limit? I need to do this for a business customer FB page I am creating.

Here is the message I posted in the group:

> I will repeat my question below... how is it that stitch can post 2400 characters to the wall, when I copied and pasted his post onto my wall I got a message:
>
> Status updates must be less than 500 characters. You have entered 2,400 characters here. Notes can be much longer. Would you like to edit and post your update as a Note instead?

Answer (score 1):

You are currently permitted to post up to **63,206 characters** on [Facebook](http://www.facebook.com/) in a status group or wall post. There is no difference.

[image: Character Chart]

> In September, we increased the character limit on status updates to 5,000 characters. Today, we're announcing that you can now write posts with more than 60,000 characters. (1)

Vadim Lavrusik
Journalism Program Manager at Facebook

> I set the exact limit to something nerdy. Facebook … Face Boo K … hex(FACE) - K … 64206 - 1000 = 63206 (2)

Bob Baldwin
Engineer at Facebook

(1) https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10101347666163140&set=a.10100111870342870.2825615.13930675&type=1

(2) http://www.zdnet.com/blog/facebook/facebook-increases-status-update-character-limit-to-63206/5754